# Use Jquery to alter an item in a selectlist?

Tags: jquery

Before:

```
<select id="NumberId" name="NumberId">
  <option value="">ZERO</option>
  <option value="4">FOUR</option>
  <option value="5">FIVE</option>
</select>
```

Using JQuery, modify the value of the option with an empty value to 0 (zero).

After:

```
<select id="NumberId" name="NumberId">
  <option value="0">ZERO</option>
  <option value="4">FOUR</option>
  <option value="5">FIVE</option>
</select>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
$("#NumberId option[value='']").val('0');
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this:

```
$("#NumberId option[value='']").attr("value", "0");
```

or

```
$("#NumberId option[value='']").val("0");
```

(not 100% sure that works with `<option>` elements)

But the more obvious thing to do is correctly generate the HTML on the serverside, no?

Comment: I agree - but in this case, I did not have the option of editing the selectlist source of this serverside, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select option[value='']").attr("value", "0");
```